# What does "und schon" mean in "Falsche Kleidung bei Regen, Schnee, und Kälte und schon tun Hals und Kopf weh"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

> Falsche Kleidung bei Regen, Schnee, und Kälte und schon tun Hals und Kopf weh

I somehow get the meaning that is

> Wet and cold clothes caused by rain and snow make neck and head hurt.

If I got it right then the subject is *Falsche Kleidung bei Regen, Schnee, und Kälte und schon* as a noun phrase acting as subject, but still I don't understand what does *und schon* mean.

Comment: One could reorder the sentence: ‘Falsche Kleidung bei Regen, Schnee und Kälte, und Hals und Kopf tun schon weh.’ The meaning is generally the same only the emphasis is sli~ghtly shifted.

Comment: [The German Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schon#Adverb) tells you it can't be a noun, and looking at the other variants only the adverb makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With proper punctuation the sentence should read:

> Falsche Kleidung bei Regen, Schnee und Kälte, und schon tun Hals und Kopf weh.

As an alternative to the last comma you could also use a dash.

This sentence has two parts. The first one

> Falsche Kleidung bei Regen, Schnee und Kälte

is a shortened construction without verb that might have a special name that I couldn't find out. Anyways, it describes some conditions or circumstances and could be understood as

> Wenn man bei Regen, Schnee und Kälte falsche Kleidung trägt

or (in a way that better matches the second part)

> Man hat nur einmal bei Regen, Schnee und Kälte falsche Kleidung getragen

The second part

> und schon tun Hals und Kopf weh

is quite a normal phrase with [*wehtun*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wehtun) as the (separable) verb and *Hals und Kopf* being the subject. *Und* serves its usual purpose as a conjunction, and *schon* is an adverb that refers to the first part, saying "the condition in part 1 being true, and *very quickly* the consequences in part 2 will follow".

So the meaning of the whole sentence is

"Wear the wrong clothes when rain or snow fall, and very quickly your head and throat will hurt."

Answer (score 1):

You can get a cold "this quick" if you wear the wrong clothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best word giving a hint on the meaning of the "schon" in this sentence would be "already".

"Wrong clothing in rain, snow and cold weather and neck an head hurt already."

It's like "do it already" means "mach schon".